# How to retrieve events created on fullcalendar on a datepicker to manage an appointment in symfony?

Tags: jquery, symfony, fullcalendar, bootstrap-datepicker

Here I realize a medical appointment site, and the two actors, who intervene are the doctor and the patient. So I set up the full calendar on the doctor's side, to be able to manage his schedules (add, modify, and delete his events) and save them in a database.And on the side of the patient, when he chooses the doctor , a date picker, with hours will appear on the appointment page and its general info. What I would like is that the patient sees on the date picker the available days of the doctor he has chosen.
The problem is that I have no idea how to match these two things (fullcalendar and datepicker), so if someone could give me a hint, or a starting point or a tutorial, I will be really grateful .
Thank you
Here is the image of the datepicker where will be made the making of an appointment:

[image]

This my jquery script:

```js
 <script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{ asset('public/js/moment.js') }}"></script>
 
 <script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
  
   <script>
              
  $('#calendar').datepicker({
                todayHighlight: true,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
                weekStart: 1,
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                language: 'fr',
            setDatesDisabled: [moment("12-25-2018", "MM-DD-YYYY"), 
                                  moment("12-25-2018", "MM-DD-YYYY")]

                
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example you were looking for. Click on the button to change disabled dates dynamically. Avec plaisir :-)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.date-range').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    weekStart: 1,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    language: 'fr',
    inputs: $('.range-start'),
    datesDisabled: ['27-08-2018', '28-08-2018', '29-08-2018']
  });
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.range-start').datepicker('setDatesDisabled', ['30-08-2018', '31-08-2018']);
    //This is where you get your DB date array using an AJAX call
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css');
.datepicker table tr td {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.datepicker table tr td.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.disabled:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="date-range">
    <div class="range-start"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="button" class="btn btn-warning">Now, disable 30 & 31</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Alfred,Sorry for my late response, but I tried the setDatesDisabled method and it does not work because the dates are not grayed out,

Comment: By the way, the dates and times that must be displayed on the picker date must be those that were recorded by the doctor, and thus grayed out the others not available.

Comment: @MohamedSacko, can you show the code where you implement `setDatesDisabled`? Please note that `getDisabledDates` in my example is just for illustration. This is where you need to write your actual date filtering. It is difficult to write a complete answer here because we would need to fully know how to retrieve  date data from your DB.

Comment: I just edited my post, and add the script. 
I tried the setdatesdisabled method just to see if the dates I indicated in parentheses will be gray, but no

Answer (score 0):

With http://www.daterangepicker.com/

You should add a function to your controller like this one to get all the dates

```
private function getDatesBetween(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end)
{
    $array = array();

    $interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach($daterange as $date) {
        $array[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    $array[] = $end->format('Y-m-d');

    return $array;
}
```

And also modify your `new` action to iterate on your saved events

```
    // this is the end of the `new` action
    $disabledDates = array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $bookings = $em->getRepository(Booking::class)->findAll();

    foreach ($bookings as $key => $booking) {
        $booking_period = $this->getDatesBetween(
            $booking->getBeginAt(),
            $booking->getEndAt()
        );

        $disabledDates = array_merge($disabledDates, $booking_period);
    }

    return $this->render('booking/new.html.twig', [
        'booking' => $booking,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'disabledDates' => json_encode($disabledDates),
    ]);
```

and finally add the config to the daterangepicker in the `new` template form

```
{# templates/booking/new.html.twig #}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var disabledDates = {{ disabledDates|raw }};

        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            isInvalidDate: function (date) {
                var formatted = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                return disabledDates.indexOf(formatted) > -1;
            }
        }, function(start, end, label) {
            console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        });
    });
</script>
```